# Allowing UUID values for ObjectIdentity.getIdentifier() in spring-security-acl

Tags: spring-security, acl

I'd like to discuss contributing a solution to allowing UUID values for ObjectIdentity.getIdentifier() in spring-security-acl, [SEC-972](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-972). The Spring Security Contributing guidelines point to Spring Security forums, which are now closed and point to Stack Overflow, so hopefully I'm asking in the right place.

My solution adds a new column to the acl_class table, class_id_type, that optionally allows you to specify the Java type for that acl_class. If you wire in a ConversionService to BasicLookupStrategy and the acl_class has a class_id_type specified, the ConversionService will be used to convert the identifier to the right type. This adds a dependency on spring-core.

The acl_class schema looks like this:

```
create table acl_class(
    id bigint generated by default as identity(start with 100) not null primary key,
    class varchar_ignorecase(100) not null,
    class_id_type varchar_ignorecase(100),
    constraint unique_uk_2 unique(class)
);
```

The definition of the lookupStrategy then looks like this:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean"/>
<!-- Declare a lookup strategy-->
<bean id="lookupStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="aclCache"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="aclAuthorizationStrategy"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="permissionGrantingStrategy"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="conversionService"/>
    <property name="permissionFactory" ref="permissionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

The tweaks to BasicLookupStrategy.convertCurrentResultIntoObject() look like this:

```
// If the Java type is a String, check to see if we can convert it to the target id type, e.g. UUID.
Serializable identifier = (Serializable) rs.getObject("object_id_identity");
if (isString(identifier) && hasValidClassIdType(rs)
        && canConvertFromStringTo(classIdTypeFrom(rs))) {

    identifier = convertFromStringTo((String) identifier, classIdTypeFrom(rs));
}
ObjectIdentity objectIdentity = new ObjectIdentityImpl(rs.getString("class"),
        identifier);
```

You can view the changes in a branch in this fork - https://github.com/pwheel/spring-security/tree/feature/acl-uuid-strings.

That branch contains some changes that are not relevant (e.g. private Maven repo) so please don't consider that branch a pull request in its own right. This change seems like a 'non-trivial' change so as per the contributing guidelines I'd like to discuss it before raising a pull request.

Note also that I found in my application I needed to implement a version of JdbcMutableAclService that uses the JdbcTemplate methods that take the SQL Types as arguments - this was because otherwise the MySQL connector maps UUID to binary rather than String, resulting in UTF-8 errors being thrown. I can add that to a pull request.

I am using this setup in production without any issues.

Are there any changes or improvements I should make before raising a pull request?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but I think this is OT for SO.

Comment: I agree it seems OT but if you follow the Contributing guidelines for Spring Security this is where you end up. I suspect they are out of date.